# Genetic algorithm for analysis of variance factor selection

Tags: statistics, sas, genetic-algorithm, anova

I'm planning to implement analysis of variance for different levels of factors, the problem is that I have 20 independent factors. Of course, the best model should include only significant factors. Is it even possible to apply genetic algorithm for factor selection? And in that case, what estimation function for model accuracy should I try use?

Comment: This question may be more appropriate for http://stats.stackexchange.com/ which is the stack exchange site for more general statistical questions. Stackoverflow is actually more for problems related directly to coding.

Comment: I really am not a statistics guy and don't know what that selection is (choosing which factors are used and which not?) but 20 doesn't seem to me like a hell of a lot. This still can be searched completely, especially if you can parallelize. But of course it also depends on the amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

The "of course" premise is wrong. You want to end up with "right" model, no matter what the p values say. Your  way leads to overfitting and incorrect variable selection. It is why stepwise regression is dead.

You have  a classic "big data" issue. There are lots of suggestions, but I would Google "feature selection". I would most likely try Lasso here.